# Is it possible to store multiple structures as a packet in one function and passed to other function and and extract there?

Tags: c++

Currently i am facing some issues in my code. I have one member function where it takes 4 arguments. Using this information, member function will filter out and store all these 4 arguments for 'n' number of calls. after 'n' number of calls it need to send all the stored information to other function and that function has to extract all the info.

Could some one please guide me that how can i do this using c++.

Thank you.

Here is sample code:

### **---------------------------------------------

-Lets say In file 'a': function beeing called.

send_message(int ID, int Level, int Data, int length);
**------------------------------------------------------------------

In File 'b'_ Function defination:

```
send_message(int ID, int Level, int Data, int length)

{

if(checking some other information)

{

 then updtate **Level**

}

if(level > some number)      
{    
 then all four arguments needs to be stored for 'n' number of calls
// this function will be called for multiple times each call's updated information needs to be added to the previous one for 'n' times then finally stored information has to be sent outside.  
}  
}
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

in file c:

This stored information has to be extracted. ----------------------

As of now i have created one structure where it has 4 members and these 4 members are passed as arguments to the function. and if arguments satisfying the criteria then it will return that structure alone. but i need all these structures should be store for 'n' number of call and need to be send at the end of 'n' number of calls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your attempt and show it to us, describing what works or doesn't work with it.

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem. It is unclear why you might want to do this. You might want to examine the *Command* and *Strategy* design patterns.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use a std::vector to store your data.

The lifetime of the vector needs to be managed so that the data remains after your function calls have finished. This could be achieved by declaring the vector variable outside of the loop where your function is called. There are other ways, but you do not provide enough detail in your question to state if alternative methods of lifetime management are required.

Comment: Tq@Das Schaf. Please also let me know if there are any other ways that are more efficient than this approach

Answer (score 0):

If you want one type of data type use something like `STL` or array of that type of data .

If you want to have multiple types of data that you don't have them with a standard order format , it means you are asking for Pipeline Communication where someone can call a function to start reading arguments `begin()` and then have functions like `pushInt ( int i ) / pushString ( std::string i ) / pushCustomStructName ( struct i )` and then call `end()` to complete reading these arguments and use these values .
( Open GL does that with `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` you can take ideas from there ) .

But I guess you could use something like `printf` function instead to save some time complexity . In order to do this you can use `arguments` by including `#include <cstdarg>`

```
void foo( const wchar_t *format , ... ) {
    va_list argv ;
    va_start ( argv , fmt ) ;

    // handle your arguments here

    va_end ( argv );

    // use your arguments here
}
```

I hope this answers your question